# Import chains in Python

Tags: python, programming-practices

If my `foo.py` is merely `foo_var = 1` and `bar.py` is merely `import foo`, I know I can write `baz.py` that says `from bar import foo_var`, but should I? (Or should I instead do `from foo import foo_var`?)

Is there any reason why chaining imports like this would be bad?

Comment: Suggested read https://towardsdatascience.com/importing-objects-from-a-python-module-can-be-risky-59dac696c51f

Comment: This read did not help me answer my question. This is about the difference between `import X` and `from X import Y`, not whether I should import from the original declaring module or from modules that imported from that original module instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's fine. The first (`from bar ...`) compiles and runs both `foo.py` and `bar.py` while the latter (`from foo ...`) only compiles and runs `foo.py`, but if `bar.py` only contains `import foo`, the overhead is negligible.